# CSS: Overriding user's print settings on Mozilla Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, printing, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'm trying to print a component in Mozilla Firefox, but the browser's own print settings are too strict. The component I'm trying to print has an absolute size, so if the browser is too narrow/too wide, the scale must be changed by the user and this isn't really optimal for customers.

[image: Too wide browser]
Too wide browser

[image: Optimal]
Optimal

Is there a way to "suggest" the `scale` etc. for printing so that they'd change, when clicking `window.print`? I'd need to get the timeline to show 8.00-23.00.

I'm using `FullCalendar`, which has its own printing component in later versions, but updating FC isn't optimal for the project.

EDIT: Some of my printing css below

```css
@media print {
  @page {
    size: landscape !important; // set's Chrome's print sideways
  }

  body {
    margin: 0;
  }

  .fc-unthemed {
    margin-top: -5rem !important;
    .fc-view-container {
      .fc-head {
        .fc-resource-area {
          width: 8% !important;
        }
        .fc-scroller {
          margin-bottom: 0 !important;
          border-bottom: #000 0.2rem solid !important;
        }
        .fc-time-area .fc-scroller .fc-scroller-canvas {
          width: 1200px;
        }
      }
      .fc-body .fc-timeline-event {
        border-top-width: 10px !important;
        height: 90px !important;
        margin-top: 1px !important;
      }
    }
  }

  table {
    width: auto;
    zoom: 60%; // was planning to use breakpoints etc. with zoom. FF not recognizing
  }

  // doesn't work, but might be wrong (haven't done much browser-specific)
  @-moz-document url-prefix() { 
    table {
      size: A4 landscape !important;
      zoom: 50%;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what version of fullCalendar are you using, exactly? Is this an issue in any other browsers, or just firefox?

Comment: 4.3.0. It's not the same with Chrome e.g., as it reads some css-commands that I've made, size--> Landscape and zoom = 50%

Comment: so you mean you've set some custom print-specific CSS (to override what fullcalendar provides) and firefox isn't recognising it? If so then you should show exactly what you've done and then maybe we can see if there's a workaround, or it's a known issue, or what.

Comment: I'll edit my post and put css there. FullCalendar doesn't give much of printing by itself, I'm just trying to get the printing window to show the wanted outcome automatically (e.g. Chrome takes the landscape, but on ff, you need to select it yourself)